# Django dynamic models creation. Fields are clashing

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using python 3.3 and Django 1.9. I need to implement multi-language support in my django models, so i decided to create duplicated fields - for example:

```
class Header:    
    ua_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ru_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    en_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ua_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ru_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    en_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have many models like this, with many fields, so i decided to create them dynamically. I wrote the function below:

```
def create_language_dependent_model(model_name: str, attrs: dict) -> models.Model:

    DEFAULT_LANGS = ('ua', 'ru', 'en')

    result_attrs = {
        '__module__': 'app.models'
    }

    for attribute_name, options in attrs.items():
        if options.get('isLanguageDependent'):
            for lang in DEFAULT_LANGS:
                result_attrs[lang + "_" + attribute_name] = options.get('field_type')
        else:
            result_attrs[attribute_name] = options.get('field_type')

    return type(
        model_name, (models.Model,), result_attrs
    )
```

And I create a model like this:

```
Header = create_language_dependent_model("Header", {
    attr_name: {'isLanguageDependent': True, 'field_type': models.CharField(max_length=100)}
        for attr_name in ('title', 'subtitle')
    })
```

However, when i try to run `makemigrations` I get the following errors:

```
....
app.Header.ru_title: (models.E006) The field 'ru_title' clashes with the field 'ru_title' from model 'app.header'.
app.Header.ru_title: (models.E006) The field 'ru_title' clashes with the field 'ru_title' from model 'app.header'.
app.Header.en_title: (models.E006) The field 'en_title' clashes with the field 'en_title' from model 'app.header'.
app.Header.en_title: (models.E006) The field 'en_title' clashes with the field 'en_title' from model 'app.header'.
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, i realized, when i try to create model using function, i pass `instance` of class `CharField` in `field_type` key.
And in function `create_language_dependent_model` in for loop, i am assigning the same instance to different model fields 
`result_attrs[lang + "_" + attribute_name] = options.get('field_type')`. In such case different fields are referencing on the same instance of `CharField`, so in result i had field clashing. The solution is to create new instance of `CharField` for each field

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to add a `language` field to the model?

```
class Header(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='en')
```

Comment: In such case i need to create for example 3 instance of that model in database, but i have concern about such implementation, because in real model i also have "common" fields, which would be the same for all instances, and many of them are ImageFields and FileFields, and i think duplication of CharFields is better then duplication of files or images. But your point is good, thanks